# Creation of collection via FXCollections from FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

There are dozens of examples with creation of collections via `FXCollections` from FXML like this (from [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements)):

```
<FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
    <String fx:value="A"/>
    <String fx:value="B"/>
    <String fx:value="C"/>
</FXCollections>
```

But I can not understand how it works. After all, factory method is **no-arg** method, so where do `String`-elements go? I have thought it is default property, but `FXCollections` has no default property. There is overloaded version of `observableArrayList()` factory method which takes vararg of collection's elements in docs and source code. But why does `FXML` use this method? It is not specified in documentation (or I can not find it). All what I found in docs is:

> The fx:factory attribute is another means of creating objects whose classes do not have a default constructor. The value of the attribute is the name of a static, no-arg factory method for producing class instances. For example, the following markup creates an instance of an observable array list, populated with three string values:

I feel it is stupid question. But could anyone make it clear for me?

Thank you in advance

P.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is overloaded version of `observableArrayList()` factory method which takes vararg of collection's elements in docs and source code. But why does FXML use this method?

It doesn't. `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` is used to create the list and since the surrounding element to the `<String>` elements is a `List`, those elements are added to the list. The java code to produce the same result would be

```
ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
```

The list is treated the same way [read-only list properties](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_list_property_elements) are, even though the documentation does not explicitly state this.